# Windows Server 2003 platform SDK

Tags: windows, sdk, windows-server-2003, winapi

I am using Windows Server 2003 x64 Enterprise with SP2 and I want to install platform SDK.

But all I find is from here, and it is called Windows® Server 2003 SP1 Platform SDK. I am confused about SP1. For my platform, should I use this version of platform SDK or some other later version (I think there should be SP2 platform SDK, but I did not find out.)

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=a55b6b43-e24f-4ea3-a93e-40c0ec4f68e5&displaylang=en

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microsoft doesn't release an SDK for every service pack of every Windows version. Instead, they release service packs along with a system release whenever the system includes new functionality. So for developing on Windows 2003, the SP1 service pack will be fine. Other options include:

- [the SDK for Windows 2003 R2](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=0baf2b35-c656-4969-ace8-e4c0c0716adb&displaylang=en)
- [the SDK for Windows Vista](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=ff6467e6-5bba-4bf5-b562-9199be864d29&displaylang=en)
- [the SDK for Windows 7](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=c17ba869-9671-4330-a63e-1fd44e0e2505&displaylang=en)
- [the SDK for Windows 2008](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=F26B1AA4-741A-433A-9BE5-FA919850BDBF&displaylang=en)

See the list of supported operating systems to verify that each of them supports Windows 2003.

Comment: Thanks! A further question Windows 2003 R2 means Windows 2003 SP2? If not, what is Windows 2003 R2?

Comment: Windows 2003 R2 was not a service pack of Windows 2003; it is a separate operating system release, introducing several new features. See http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003/r2launch.mspx

Comment: Thanks, 1. looks like it is between Windows Server 2003 SP1 and Windows Server SP2 as a separate release? 2. So, for Windows Server 2003 platform SDK, can I understand that the SDK for Windows 2003 R2 should be the most recent platform SDK I can use?

Comment: 1. No; Windows 2003 and Windows 2003 R2 are separate releases. SP1 and SP2 are service packs (not releases). SP1 applies only to 2003; SP2 applies to both 2003 and 2003 R2. 2. No, the most recent SDK for Windows 2003 is the Windows 2008 SDK.

Comment: Thanks Martin, the last question, I am confused that you said "the most recent SDK for Windows 2003 is the Windows 2008 SDK" -- I want to confirm if I want to use platform SDK on Windows Server 2003 x64 Enterprise SP2, the most recent version I should select Windows Server 2008 SDK? I have such confusion because I think Windows Server 2008 SDK is for developing/utilizing function provided by Server 2008 OS, but I am developing application targeting for Windows Server 2003. Any comments or ideas?

Comment: Windows 2008 SDK supports targeting windows XP, 2003, Vista and 2008.

Comment: All of the links provided are broken.